# how to align RelativeView to stick to the bottom

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a fairly large layout file which are part of an TabHost, my problem is that the last RelativeLayout (@id/footbar) won't stick to the bottom of my view no matter what attribute I use, it seems.

Please give me an idea to realize that. I want the ListView to be **between** the placeholder (hline) and the footbar.

Currently the footbar sticks to the List which is aligned correctly at the top, but extends with its contents. When I choose the list to have a height of **"match_parent"** or **"fill_parent"** it takes all the space to the bottom and moves footbar out of the view :(

BTW: Is there a way to get the scaled ImageButton to fit to the height of the spinner or the way round?

Thank's in advance

Here's the listing:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/abrtimer">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/username_timer"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/hline"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="2dip"
               android:background="#544444"
               android:layout_below="@id/username_timer" />

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_below="@id/hline"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
         <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/timerList"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                            android:gravity="top"/>

         <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                     android:layout_below="@id/timerList"
                     android:id="@+id/footbar"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     android:gravity="bottom"
                     android:weightSum="10">

             <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/projectSpinner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="8"/>
            <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
                android:id="@+id/addButton"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>      
         </LinearLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thinks this code is what you need. It's simplified a little. You don't really need to use `RelativeLayout`s to implement this layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/abrtimer">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/username_timer"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/hline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#544444" />

    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/timerList"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/timerList"
        android:id="@+id/footbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/projectSpinner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="8"/>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>      
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```